# I need help coding something in R using base R packages

Tags: r

So I am working on a problem that wants me to take the Quake data in R and seperate it into a factor vector of the given depths and then create a boxplot of the different categories. Then run a Kruskal Wallis test on it.

This is what I have.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Load the quakes data
data(quakes)

# Create a new factor vector defining the depths of each event according to the given categories
quakes <- quakes %>%
  mutate(depth_cat = cut(depth, breaks = c(0, 200, 400, 680), labels = c("[0,200]", "(200,400]", "(400,680]")))

# Use a boxplot to visually compare the distributions of the number of detecting stations, split according to the three categories of depth
ggplot(quakes, aes(x = depth_cat, y = stations)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(x = "Depth Category", y = "Number of Detecting Stations")

# Since the distributions of the number of detecting stations appear to be skewed, we will use a Kruskal-Wallis test to compare the distributions of the three depth categories.
kruskal.test(stations ~ depth_cat, data = quakes, na.action = na.exclude)

#The output of the Kruskal-Wallis test shows a p-value of less than 0.01, which indicates that there is strong evidence of a difference in the distributions of the number of detecting stations between the three depth categories. Therefore, we reject the null hypothesis that the distributions are the same and conclude that there is a significant difference in the number of detecting stations between the different depth categories.
```

This code works, and using resources this is how I solved it. I need help coding it using base R functions instead of what I have, as that is what teh assignment specifies.

Comment: The naive approach would be to change `%>%` to `|>`, and change `mutate` to `transform`, and now it's base R. On the other end, `kruskal.test` is already base R. So ... have you tried anything with `boxplot(..)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cut` is a base R function and the `stats` package where the `kruskal.test` is found is one of R's base packages, so the only parts which I've changed are how the `depth_cat` variable is added and how the plot is assembled.

```r
data(quakes)

quakes$depth_cat = cut(quakes$depth, breaks = c(0,200,400,680), labels = c("[0,200]", "(200,400]", "(400,680]"))

boxplot(stations ~ depth_cat, data = quakes,
        xlab = 'Depth Category', ylab = 'Number of Detecting Stations')
```

[image]

```r
kruskal.test(stations ~ depth_cat, data = quakes, na.action = na.exclude)
#> 
#>  Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
#> 
#> data:  stations by depth_cat
#> Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 9.0943, df = 2, p-value = 0.0106
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>